# Plot data of a given subject

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I did a linear regression with random effects using R and the `lme` function :

```
ana1 <- lme(Y ~ 1+X,data,random = list(group=pdDiag(~1+X)))
```

where `Y` are my observations, `X` the vector of regressors and `group` a grouping vector (each element of `group` is a number between 1 and N which indicates to which subject the observation belongs).

After doing the linear regression, I can obtain fitted values using :

```
fit <- fitted(ana1)
```

What I would like to do is : create a function which takes as arguments `ana1` and `k`, a number between 1 and N, and plot (on the same plot) the observations for subject k and the fitted values (with different colors).

I don't know how to do this. I have the feeling that this can be done using `predict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot(Y~X,data) #To plot all data
points(data$X[k],predict(ana1,data[k,]),col='red') #add a predicted point in red
```